# mail function, don't wait for respons in shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer, shared-hosting

I have a script that sends data to a table in mysql database and now I've wanted to generate an email everytime someone adds new data. It works, but as you may know, it lasts almost 20-30 secs to complete and get the response.
I´ve read that exec function would have been good for executing mail() in a separate file, but at my shared server exec is disabled. Also are disabled these others:

```
symlink,shell_exec,exec,proc_close,proc_open,popen,system,dl,passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,show_source,pcntl_exec
```

Anybody can show how can I make this posible without blocking webpage until email is sent?

Thankyou!

Comment: you should ask your hoster, how they think sending mail should work. they probably will be much more capable of helping than anyone here could be.

Comment: SMTP to localhost using PHPMailer may be faster. If submitting a message to a local mail server (via `mail()` or SMTP) is taking more than about 0.2 sec, you're doing something wrong, or there's something wrong with your server.

Answer (score 0):

the mail function looks like this. Is something in it making it slow??

```
$to      = "xxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "xxxxx";
$message = "xxxxxxxxx: \n";
$message .= "\n";
$message .= "   $getuser\n";
$message .= "\n";
$headers = 'From: xxxx@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: xxx@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headerxs);
```